# Offline file viewing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, model-view-controller, offline-caching

I am working an MVC for project and MSSQL database backend. The project can be view outside even in mobile browser,

This is the workflow, The project have two users the "Admin" and the "User", admin will upload a pdf file and user can view the pdf file that admin upload.  Is it possible that when the user is offline or doesn't have the access to the net he can still view the page and can download or view the pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

For showing those PDF file locally when User is offline, You can do one simlest thing is that

```
1) Store the Files opened today(or in few days) in 'App_Data' folder.

2) Write some process in your server side to check whether the PDF file is present in App_Data or not.

If(File present in App_Data Folder)
{
   //We Can Open that PDF File Locally
}
else
{
   //Stream those PDF Files and store it in App_Data for further use.
}
```